# 401 while making API call from Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

We have an internal website, which supports working with API also. When i access an API URI in browser i'm getting `JSON response`, but if i make the same call from Excel i'm getting `401, invalid credentials`. Please find my VBA Code below.

```
Dim Serv2 As New WinHttpRequest

Sub Conn()

Url = "https://uri/api/nag/"

     With Serv2

        .Open "GET", Url, False
        .Send

        MsgBox .Status & "       " & .ResponseText

    End With

   Set Serv2 = Nothing

End Sub
```

Note: The url provided is sample data.

Many Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: So it wants credentials of some type & you have not provided any ...  You need to check the docs or ask the maintainer.

Comment: I tried passing the credentials as headers but it returns the same. :(

Comment: Even the API works perfectly with Postman also, with out credentials.

Comment: So you need to add the code your using in VBA to send the credentials & what the equivalent working postman request look like.

Comment: This is the part which is messing up my head. In postman request i didn't add any additional headers. If i fill the URI and click send I'm receiving 200 OK with correct response JSON. Only difference i see in Post man code and my code is "Postman Token".

Comment: Your request is a GET so does it work if you just load the url into a browser address bar?

Comment: Yes, if i feed in request in chrome i'm able to see the response.

Comment: Add a believable u/a: `Serv2.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.29 Safari/537.36"`

Comment: No luck mate, still at the same point.